Iterator returns deleted data
I am trying to delete data from rocksdb using iterator and once the data is deleted completely I tried using a new iterator to get data and I am able to see deleted data. Here is the deletion code snippet
rocksdb_iter_seek(iter, prefixdata, prefixlen);
while(rocksdb_iter_valid(iter))
{
    const char *rocksdb_cf_key = rocksdb_iter_key(iter, &keylen);
    char key[keylen];
    memcpy(key, rocksdb_cf_key, keylen);
    rocksdb_writebatch_wi_delete_cf(wbwi, columnFamilyHandle, key, keyLen); // uses writebatch->delete();
    // rocksdb_delete_cf(columnFamilyHandle, key, keyLen); -- uses db->delete
    rocksdb_iter_next(iter);
}

I tried using with write batch and without write batch but I am still facing the issue. If I delete the data without using iterator I am not getting this issue so I am not able to figure out where the bug is. This is only happening when my dataset is too huge and I also tried restarting server but that didn't work.
Please let me know if you need more information
